# ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 475

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from oracle using this c# code:

```
string extension = Filename_Box.Text.Substring(Filename_Box.Text.IndexOf('.'));
                string package_query = "";

                //Run the appropriate package/procedure for the file
                switch(extension)
                {
                    case ".400":
                    case ".500":
                    case ".901":
                    case ".301":
                    case ".303":
                        //Just for testing, remove for production
                        package_query = @"CREDIT_CARD.READ_ECI_CC";
                        //package_query = @"INTERFACE.CREDIT_CARD.READ_ECI_CC";
                        break;
                    case ".200":
                        package_query = @"CREDIT_CARD.READ_ECI_NEWFORMAT_CC";
                        //package_query = @"INTERFACE.CREDIT_CARD.READ_ECI_NEWFORMAT_CC";
                        break;
                    case ".DAT":
                        package_query = @"CREDIT_CARD.READ_INSPRO_CC";
                        //package_query = @"INTERFACE.CREDIT_CARD.READ_INSPRO_CC";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                using (OracleConnection package_connection = new OracleConnection(connection_string))
                {
                    OracleCommand package_command = package_connection.CreateCommand();

                    package_command.CommandText = package_query;
                    package_command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    package_command.Parameters.Add("p_filename", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Filename_Box.Text;

                    try
                    {
                        package_connection.Open();
                        package_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

What does this error message mean and how can I fix it?
The detailed error message is as follows:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x00007263):
>   ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line
>   475 ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at
>   "ACANZONE.CREDIT_CARD", line 530 ORA-06512: at line 1 at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl
>   connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors,
>   OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB,
>   Boolean bFirstIterationDone) at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl
>   connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors,
>   OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean
>   bFirstIterationDone) at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType
>   commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize,
>   Int32 lobPrefetchSize, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl,
>   Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection&
>   bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Boolean isFromEF)
>   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   Credit_Card_Processing.MainWindow.search_button_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   x:\GIT_REPOS\C_SHARP_CODE\USER_INTERFACES\Credit_Card_Processing\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   157

Comment: Who knows?  The error is coming from within the oracle procedure you are calling, and probably has nothing to do with C#, unless your parameters are messed-up.  All we know is that somwhere in your CREDIT_CARD package, there is a call to UTL_FILE that is causing an error. What happens when you call the package function directly through pl/sql?

Comment: It fails with the same error as above @OldProgrammer

Comment: Oracle hasn't privileges to read/write in location or you try to access remote location and utl_file can only access local server

Comment: Then the error is in the package, and you need to debug that.